# Iteratively process with RDD can't last long

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, mesos

I need to join 2 RDDs which are too big to load and join in a single processing. So I fetch some records from source RDD and destination RDD and join them iteratively. But I found with time went by the join speed became slower and slower and at last the program stopped at a certain stage. The stage's status was staging and never changed. It seems that the RDDs declared in the iteration had not been freed and thus the system has no enough memory for new RDDs. How to fix it?

```
var A: RDD[(Int, UUID)] = …
var B: RDD[(Int, UUID)] = …
for (i <- 0 until 64) {
    var tmpA = A.filter(x => x._1%64 == i)
    var tmpB = B.filter(x => x._1%64 == i)
    var C = A.join(B)
    println(C.count)
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if you can use an alternative approach. What about splitting your RDDs into smaller partitions and then performing the join?

Comment: If I directly join A with B, the C is too big. Increasing parallelism is useless.

Comment: How large are `A` and `B` ?  What happens when you try to `join` them at once? What error do you get?

Comment: Also, what happens to `C` after that process? I guess you are `union`ing new parts to `C` ?

Comment: A has 524837903 records. B has 524494411 records. C has 262687617928 records. My spark clusters has a driver which set memory to 8G and 8 executors which set the memories to 32G. If I join A with B, the error message is as follows: "Lost executor 20161116-150349-356456620-5050-3433-S4 on dell6: Executor heartbeat timed out after 139567 ms." Apparently C can't be loaded into executors at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe at least part of your issue is that the original RDDs can't get out of memory. In each step you basically load them to memory in order to do the filter.
Instead you can split them into multiple RDDS and save each to disk. Then load only the relevant pair when you do the join. This means that by the next join it can release everything else.

That said, assuming your sample represents your actual code, it seems you have a schema for your RDD. I would try either using datasets or even better dataframes which take less memory (from my experience this can easily be a factor of 10) and then everything might fit in memory.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try both of your 2 suggestions.